# Adjust markeredge style independent of line style in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm struggling to get a NICE line plot with a dashed line and markers at the moment. I boiled it down in the following bit of code. There it seems that the line style (dashed) is used for the markeredge line style, which is not what I want. Does anyone know a way around that? 
It looks quite messy when using "filled" markers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      xlabel={$xlabel$},
      ylabel={ylabel},
      clip mode=individual,
      xmin=0.4, xmax=4.1,
      ymin=0.001, ymax=0.2,
      axis on top,
      width=12cm,
      height=12cm,
      ]
      \addplot [thick,dashed, blue, mark=o, mark size=5, mark options={rotate=180}]
      coordinates {
      (0.5,0.050434357296103)
      (1,0.0078648549533149)
      (1.5,0.0106056739726252)
      (2,0.0693259848345091)
      (2.5,0.0521069487623915)
      (3,0.0870245544201076)
      (4,0.121893601793102)
      };
      \addplot [thick,dashed, green, mark=*, mark size=5]
      coordinates {
      (0.5,0.12)
      (1,0.15)
      (3,0.18)
      };          
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `solid` for the `mark options` so the mark border won't inherit the `dashed` style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      xlabel={$xlabel$},
      ylabel={ylabel},
      clip mode=individual,
      xmin=0.4, xmax=4.1,
      ymin=0.001, ymax=0.2,
      axis on top,
      width=12cm,
      height=12cm,
      ]
      \addplot [thick,dashed, blue, mark=o, mark size=5, mark options={rotate=180,solid}]
      coordinates {
      (0.5,0.050434357296103)
      (1,0.0078648549533149)
      (1.5,0.0106056739726252)
      (2,0.0693259848345091)
      (2.5,0.0521069487623915)
      (3,0.0870245544201076)
      (4,0.121893601793102)
      };
      \addplot [thick,dashed, green, mark=*, mark size=5,mark options={solid}]
      coordinates {
      (0.5,0.12)
      (1,0.15)
      (3,0.18)
      };          
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If this is going to apply to all the marks, it's better to set this using

```
 \tikzset{every mark/.append style={solid}}
```

so you don't have to use the option each time:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\tikzset{every mark/.append style={solid}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      xlabel={$xlabel$},
      ylabel={ylabel},
      clip mode=individual,
      xmin=0.4, xmax=4.1,
      ymin=0.001, ymax=0.2,
      axis on top,
      width=12cm,
      height=12cm,
      ]
      \addplot [thick,dashed, blue, mark=o, mark size=5]
      coordinates {
      (0.5,0.050434357296103)
      (1,0.0078648549533149)
      (1.5,0.0106056739726252)
      (2,0.0693259848345091)
      (2.5,0.0521069487623915)
      (3,0.0870245544201076)
      (4,0.121893601793102)
      };
      \addplot [thick,dashed, green, mark=*, mark size=5]
      coordinates {
      (0.5,0.12)
      (1,0.15)
      (3,0.18)
      };          
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Congratulations on your recent 200K reputation achievement.  Well deserved!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thank you for your kind words!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought I've tried that before, but it seems I have not. The default option is pretty neat, even though I produce the graphs with a script themselves. Thanks!